# pass varible in collection resource laravel api

Tags: php, laravel, api, resources

i have this function

```
public function activityAutoDeposit(GoalRequest $request)
{
    $goal = Goal::find($request->input('goal_id'));
    if($goal->user_id != auth()->id()) {
        return $this->responseData([], 'forbidden card', true);
    }
    $schedule_deposit = DB::table('rules')
        ->join('cards', 'rules.card_id', '=', 'cards.id')
        ->join('rules_schedule_deposits', 'rules.id', '=', 'rules_schedule_deposits.rule_id')
        ->select('rules_schedule_deposits.*')
        ->where('table', '=', 'rules_schedule_deposits')
        ->where('cards.user_id', '=', auth()->id())
        ->get();

   
    return $this->responseData(AutoDepositResource::collection($schedule_deposit ,$goal->distribution->percentage ));
}
```

i want to pass the varible `$goal->distribution->percentage` to the resource collection .. i wrote in AutoDepositResource class this constructor

```
public $att;

public function __construct($resource , $att)
{
    #parent::__construct($resource);
    $this->resource = $resource;
    $this->att = $att;
}
```

but the value i get 0 , 1 ,2 +++ .. i did not recive the correct value

Answer (score 0):

JsonResource does not support multiple parameters. Use single resource parameter.

```
public function activityAutoDeposit(GoalRequest $request)
{
    $resource = (object) [
        'schedule_deposit' => $schedule_deposit,
        'goal_distribution_percentage' => $goal->distribution->percentage,
    ];

    return $this->responseData(
        AutoDepositResource::collection($resource)
    );
}
```

```
class AutoDepositResource extends JsonResource
{
    public function toArray($request)
    {
        return [
            'schedule_deposit' => $this->schedule_deposit,
            'goal_distribution_percentage' => $this->goal_distribution_percentage,
        ];
    }
}
```